# Flutter show array in future or stream builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple array I created it globally in some file and use it in my whole app. I simply created .dart file and add this line.

```
var my_global_Array = [];
```

Now what i am doing is i am inserting data in this like

```
my_global_Array.add({'name': 'abx', 'age': 22});
```

Lets suppose i have added multiple records My array now look like this

```
my_global_Array = [{'name': 'abx', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'abx2', 'age': 12}];
```

I need to show this array in Streambuilder or futurebuilder. Why ? Yes I can show this in ListViewbuilder but issue I am facing is I have a page on which I am showing this records and on second page I am adding these thing in array so I can show my array by ListViewBuilder in second page but I cant update it on my first page so that's why I think i need to use Stream or Futurebuilder i search for it but not find any answer to shwo array in Stream or Future.

Comment: You should look into state management for flutter. I am pretty sure that you don't need a Stream or FutureBuilder for this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 1):

This will be your function that will return a List of Maped data from an array.

```
       Future<List<ModelClass>> fetchData() async {
         List data = jsonDecode(my_global_Array);
         return data.map((user) => ModelClass.fromJson(user)).toList();
      }
```

And this will be a model class for your data used in function,

```
class ModelClass{
  final name;
  final age;
  ModelClass({this.age,this.name});
  factory  ModelClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return ModelClass(
      age: json['age'] as int,
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

You just assign **`fetchData()`** to a variable inside **InitState** and then use that variable inside  **StreamBuilder**  like

```
stream:variable.asStram(),
```

After all Yor StreamBuilder will look

```
StramBuilder<List<ModelClass>>(
stream:fetchData().asStream(),
builder:(context, snapshot){

return
ListView.Builder(
itemCount:snapshot.length,
builder:(cont,index){

return Text(' Name: ${snapshot[index].name}\n Age: ${snapshot[index].age}');
}
);}
);
```